# Is there any reason to play Halcyon 6: Starbase Commander over the Lightspeed Edition?

Tags: version-differences, halcyon-6

both [*Halcyon 6: Starbase Commander*](https://store.steampowered.com/app/371200/Halcyon_6_Starbase_Commander/) and [*Halcyon 6: Starbase Commander LIGHTSPEED EDITION*](https://store.steampowered.com/app/651660/Halcyon_6_Starbase_Commander_LIGHTSPEED_EDITION/) sell a bundle that includes both game with the Lightspeed Edition saying

> Halcyon 6: Lightspeed Edition brings together the original Halcyon 6 base game along with all of the additional content (Combat & Customization, Diplomatic Diversions, Loot’em Up, and Morale Booster updates) released since launch in Sept 2016 as well as brand new Lightspeed Edition optimizations and features as

which makes me think that Lightspeed Edition has everything that's in the original game. yet if that was the case it seems odd that i can't just guy the Lightspeed Edition by itself.

So is there any reason to play *Halcyon 6: Starbase Commander* over the Lightspeed Edition? ie. content that is only in the original game or a different plot that's not in the lightspeed edition?

Answer (score 1):

The store page tells you what the Lightspeed editions features are if you continue reading below the part you quoted.

The developer also posted a more detailed list of changes between the versions as well if you would like to [look at it here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/651660/discussions/0/1471967615865750572/).

Specifically they mention that the campaigns are the same so there are no separate plot lines or anything story related you will be missing out on from one version to the other. Emphasis my own.

> Overall, the campaign takes a much shorter time to complete (down to about 12-15 hrs instead of 20-25 hrs) **but no content was removed**, we only adjusted the overall progression to be faster and require much less grinding.